# Exponential Random Variable and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-function, conditional-probability, queueing-theory

Person 1 enters a queue, Person 1 will eventually abandon this queue, where his impatience is an exponential random variable with rate $θ$. In $s$ minutes later Person 2 will enter the system and will abandon the queue eventually too. Person 2's impatience is also an exponential random variable, is independent of Person 1's patience with rate $μ$. What is the probability that Person 1 will abandon the queue before Person 2 does?

Comment: what do you know? can you write out for example the CDF of the exponential distribution, or your ideas? What did you try?

Comment: Would the CDF of the exponential distribution for the problem be 1-e^(-θ/μ) ?

Comment: @Harry No, see my answer.

Comment: @math1000 thanks I saw, you shared it after I made that comment

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1$ be the time that person 1 spends in the queue and $X_2$ the time that person 2 spends in the queue. The probability that person 1 abandons the queue before person 2 is
$$
\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant s) + \mathbb P(s\leqslant X_1\leqslant s+X_2).
$$
The first probability follows directly from the distribution function of $X_1$:
$$
\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant s) = 1 - e^{-\theta s}.
$$
For the second probability, we integrate over the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(s\leqslant X_1\leqslant s+X_2) &= \iint_{(x,y):s<x<s+y} f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_s^{s+y}\theta e^{-\theta x}\mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dx \ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac{\theta  e^{-\theta  -s}}{\theta +\mu }.
\end{align}
Hence the overall probability is 
$$
1 - e^{-\theta s} + \frac{\theta  e^{-\theta  -s}}{\theta +\mu } = 1-\frac{\mu  e^{-\theta  s}}{\theta +\mu }.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- What is the probability that Person 1 is still in the queue at time $s$?
- If they are both in the queue at the same time, what is the probability that Person 1 leaves first?